# Adding Model display "Yes" to a jscript function which gets total from radio button inputs of value "1"

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-2

any ideas on how to resolve whats below?

Edit- seems some people don't understand the issue from the title and the code so here it is, I have a running total which increases each time a radio button on my page is changed but I have 4 forms which have radio buttons and each after being saved has a display view instead of edit, my issue is I don't know how best to get the display value into my total function.
Also in the display view I have the 2 different ways in which my questions are displayed, switch for 3 forms and rest for final form.

Edit2- Noticed that some people think if code is all they see at the top of page then some don't read down to text so moving it up to top in hopes of making it clearer

Edit view

```
<td class="aCell">          
                        <%= Html.RadioButton(i+"_1", "1", new { @onclick = "getTotal()", @class = "sectionCB" }) %>                 
                    </td>
                    <td class="aCell">
                        <%= Html.RadioButton(i+"_1", "0", new { @onclick = "getTotal()", @class = "sectionCB", @checked = "checked" })%>
```

Display view

```
switch (i)
                       {
                           case 1:
                               {
                                   qna1 = (Model.Q1A1) ? "Yes" : "No";
                                   qna2 = (Model.Q1A2) ? "Yes" : "No";
                                   break;
                               }
<tr>
                    <td class="bCell" >
                        H/k
                        </td>
                    <td class="aCell" colspan="2"><%: (Model.Q9A1) ? "Yes" : "No"%></td>
```

Total function

```
function getTotal() {
        var $inputs = $('#dAnswers :input.sectionCB');
        var x = 0;
        $inputs.each(function () {

            if ($(this).val() == "1" && $(this).attr('checked')) { x++; }

        });

        var total = Math.round(x / 51 * 100);
        $('#sTotal').html(total + '%');
}
```

Total display

```
<span style="font-size: 250%;" id="sTotal">0%</span>
```

Comment: *"any ideas then?"* - about what exactly? All you've done is pasted some untidy looking code, you haven't described what the problem is.

Comment: the title describes exactly what the problem is, I have code which works for edit view to get a total but I don't know how I can get the display view to produce the same results

Comment: try passing the value to the `getTotal()` function, instead of going back to the DOM and finding it each time. e.g ` @onclick = "getTotal(this.value)"`

Comment: didn't keep the value, still lost the total once the form was saved and redirected back to same page with that form in display view

Comment: otherwise would creating a new database table column for each form help so as to make it easier?(if so how would I get the % on the page to correctly add up the total, I'd preferably not want to store these values in the database since they are only really needed for the users using the system and not key data which can't be got better with other means)

Comment: deadline fast approaching and looks like nobody knows or just nobody is looking at this anymore

Comment: Guess this will never get answered then